# How Can I Access MongoDB _id of logged in user?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, body-parser

I want to store new string that user input and submit in collections into logged in user data.

By using
`console.log(req.user);`
I get all user data with _id.
But using `console.log(req.user.id)`, I'm getting `undefined` value.

Comment: You can get the "internal" mongoDB _id by `user._id`

Comment: The variable name is not called `id`, it's `_id`. Use `req.user["_id"]`